# opengl - LookAt with near and far

Tags: c#, opengl

I'm new to opengl and matrices in general but I've got my camera class to work in first person mode, But things are dissappearing and I would like to know if there is any way to set the near and far clipping planes when I'm only using a model view and view matrix

I've only got this at the moment,

```
        Matrix4 view = Matrix4.LookAt
        (
            cam_pos[0],
            cam_pos[1],
            cam_pos[2],
            cam_pos[0] + cam_view[0],
            cam_pos[1] + cam_view[1],
            cam_pos[2] + cam_view[2],
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
       );

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.LoadMatrix(ref view);
```

here is my full class:

```
namespace opengl.Cameras
{
    using opengl.Components;
    using OpenTK;
    using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System;

    public class BasicCamera : CameraComponent, IComponent
    {
        const float sensitivity = 0.002f;
        const float walk_speed = 100.5f;

        float[] cam_pos = {75.5f, 30.0f, -110};
        float[] cam_view = {-0.0f, 0.0f, 0.7f};

        static int old_x, old_y;

        void normalize(float[] v)
        {
            float magnitude = (float)Math.Sqrt(v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1] + v[2] * v[2]);           
            v[0] /= magnitude;
            v[1] /= magnitude;
            v[2] /= magnitude;
        }

        void rotate_view(float[] view, float angle, float x, float y, float z)
        {
            float new_x;
            float new_y;
            float new_z;

            float c = (float)Math.Cos(angle);
            float s = (float)Math.Sin(angle);

            new_x = (x * x * (1 - c) + c) * view[0];
            new_x += (x * y * (1 - c) - z * s) * view[1];
            new_x += (x * z * (1 - c) + y * s) * view[2];

            new_y = (y * x * (1 - c) + z * s) * view[0];
            new_y += (y * y * (1 - c) + c) * view[1];
            new_y += (y * z * (1 - c) - x * s) * view[2];

            new_z = (x * z * (1 - c) - y * s) * view[0];
            new_z += (y * z * (1 - c) + x * s) * view[1];
            new_z += (z * z * (1 - c) + c) * view[2];

            view[0] = new_x;
            view[1] = new_y;
            view[2] = new_z;

            normalize(view);
        }

        void motion(int x, int y)
        {
            float rot_x, rot_y;
            float[] rot_axis = new float[3];

            x -= Viewport.Width / 2;
            y -= Viewport.Height / 2;

            rot_x = -(float)(x - old_x) * sensitivity;
            rot_y = -(float)(y - old_y) * sensitivity;

            old_x = x;
            old_y = y;

            rotate_view(cam_view, rot_x, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

            rot_axis[0] = -cam_view[2];
            rot_axis[1] = 0.0f;
            rot_axis[2] = cam_view[0];

            normalize(rot_axis);

            rotate_view(cam_view, rot_y, rot_axis[0], rot_axis[1], rot_axis[2]);
        }

        public BasicCamera() :  base()
        {
            // Enable depth testing
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
            GL.ClearDepth(1.0f);
        }

        public void Load(CameraComponent Camera)
        {
        }

        public void UpdateFrame(double elapsed)
        {
            if (this[Keys.W])
            {
                cam_pos[0] += cam_view[0] * walk_speed;
                cam_pos[1] += cam_view[1] * walk_speed;
                cam_pos[2] += cam_view[2] * walk_speed;
            }
            if (this[Keys.S])
            {
                cam_pos[0] -= cam_view[0] * walk_speed;
                cam_pos[1] -= cam_view[1] * walk_speed;
                cam_pos[2] -= cam_view[2] * walk_speed;
            }
            if (this[Keys.A])
            {
                cam_pos[0] += cam_view[2] * walk_speed;
                cam_pos[2] -= cam_view[0] * walk_speed;
            }
            if (this[Keys.D])
            {
                cam_pos[0] -= cam_view[2] * walk_speed;
                cam_pos[2] += cam_view[0] * walk_speed;
            }

            if (this[Keys.Space])
                cam_pos[1] += walk_speed;
        }

        public void Render(double elapsed)
        {
            Matrix4 view = Matrix4.LookAt
            (
                cam_pos[0],
                cam_pos[1],
                cam_pos[2],
                cam_pos[0] + cam_view[0],
                cam_pos[1] + cam_view[1],
                cam_pos[2] + cam_view[2],
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
           );

            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
            GL.LoadMatrix(ref view);
        }

        public void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            old_x = (int)e.X - Viewport.Width / 2;
            old_y = (int)e.Y - Viewport.Height / 2;
        }

        public void OnMouseMotion(Vector2 MousePosition, Vector2 PrevMousePosition)
        {           
            motion((int)MousePosition.X, (int)MousePosition.Y);
        }

        public void Destroy()
        {
        }

        public void Load()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer is No. Although it is possible to setup the clipping plains using glClipPlain(), using this function does not override the default clipping planes setup by the projection matrix(which by default is (1.0 near and -1.0 far, I think) orthographic) as a result objects that go out of these clipping plains will disappear, unless you setup your own projection matrices which is very easy:
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glFrustum(-left_side, right_side, -bottom, top, near, -far)
*note these functions are actually deprecated
You can use the matrices setup here in your vertex shaders by retrieving them using glFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, modview);
glUniformMatrix4fv(vert_shader, 1, false, modview);
*modview in this case would be your 16 float element array to hold your matrix values
*vert_shader your shader I'd

Details about these shader functions and such you can should know yourself or else read any of the highly abundant tutorials online. I'm a noobie myself and I hope in some way I have helped you ;)

Comment: The near clip plane is -1.0 and far is 1.0 by default in OpenGL. Which makes sense, considering in clip-space z=-1.0 is the nearest Z value and z=1.0 is the farthest Z value. Usually when you use a non-identity modelview matrix you no longer provide coordinates in NDC space, so having clip planes defined by -1.0 and 1.0 does not make a lot of sense anymore. The best place to do this is usually the projection matrix, it needs to know the range of Z values anyway for proper perspective projection.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to incorporate a projection matrix into your class. I assume you have an orthogonal type output at the moment, as OpenGL usually uses a unit cube by default.

Constructing a matrix in the following way would allow you to change the near and far planes, at least for a orthographic projection.

[image: wiki]

[from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection_%28geometry%29)

Where right/left/top/bottom/far/near are the faces of the cube. You then need to call glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION) and load this new projection matrix. It's been a while since I used immediate mode, so this step may be incorrect.

[Here is another good reference](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html)